# sObject type 'Store' is not supported

Tags: apex, soql, relationships, b2b-commerce

I am new to Salesforce and currently trying to query the fields from the Store object related to the OrderSummary standard object. Store has a lookup relationship with OrderSummary object.

First, I tried to do a normal child->parent SOQL query but received below error

```
Select Id, SalesStore.Description from OrderSummary where Id = 'MY_ID'
```

> No such column 'Description' on entity 'Name'

Upon some research I found that this maybe because the field is polymorphic. I ran below code and the result of method `isNamePointing` is true.

```
System.debug(OrderSummary.SalesStoreId.getDescribe().isNamePointing());
```

Then I tried using the `TYPEOF` clause as below but got another error.

```
Select Id, TypeOf SalesStore When Store Then Description END from OrderSummary where Id = '1Os7a0000004DWSCA2'
```

> sObject type 'Store' is not supported.

I also tried another variant of `TYPEOF` clause as below but got another error

```
Select Id, TypeOf SalesStoreId When Store Then Description END from OrderSummary where Id = '1Os7a0000004DWSCA2'
```

> No such relation 'SalesStoreId' on entity 'OrderSummary'.

So, how can I query the fields of the Store object associated with the OrderSummary object.

***Data Model***

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: try `Select Id, TypeOf SalesStoreId When WebStore Then Description END from OrderSummary where Id = 'MY_ID'`

Comment: @cropredy: I tried that and the error I received is `No such relation 'SalesStoreId' on entity 'OrderSummary'. `

Comment: my bad, try `Select Id, TypeOf SalesStore When WebStore Then Description END from OrderSummary where Id = 'MY_ID'`

Comment: @cropredy: thank you. The query executed fine i.e. without any error but I do not get any fields related to WebStore object back. See screenshot https://postimg.cc/jCCLZfhD. I tried with different fields as well but similar result. To my surprise, the column for field Description itself is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this query

```
SELECT Id, TypeOf SalesStore WHEN WebStore THEN Description END 
 FROM OrderSummary WHERE Id = 'MY_ID'
```

The `TypeOf` must name the relationship name (which is `SalesStore`)

The reason you don't see the result in Developer Console (DC) is a limitation of the query editor in DC.

If you change the query in DC to:

```
SELECT Id, TypeOf SalesStore WHEN WebStore THEN Description END 
 FROM OrderSummary WHERE Id = 'MY_ID' AND SalesStore.Type = 'WebStore'
```

then the DC will show a column called `SalesStore` with a value `[object Object]` that you can't inspect.  However, if you use Apex for the first SOQL, you'll be able to debug/use the value of the `SalesStore` relationship

If you use a modern IDE (I used Illuminated Cloud), the first query will display the value of `SalesStore.Description` in the IDE's query tool.

Comment: Thank you! works like a charm

Answer (score -3):

Try:

```
Select Id, SalesStoreId.Description from OrderSummary where Id = 'MY_ID'
```

looks like the API name of the field is SalesStoreId and not SalesStore

Comment: ?? relationship names are not suffixed by `Id`, the doc says the relationship name is `SalesStore`

Comment: You are right, need to use the Relation name. however, sometime for custom fields you need to use the name of the lookup field by changing the __c for __r. But I don't think this is the case

Comment: N.B. always (not sometimes) for custom lookup fields you use `__r`